# Testing Azure functions locally for Microsoft Graph API change notifications

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying out Microsoft Graph API Change Notification(for users) in Azure Function.
There are 2 endpoints in my Azure function solution,

1. Timer Function : Create subscription with Graph API
2. Http Trigger Function : which validates and receives notification from Graph API.

I created a self-signed certificate and exposed the http trigger functions via https, so it is now of the format "https://locahost:port number/notification".

But when I try to create the subscription I am getting error "Code: InvalidRequest Message: Unable to connect to the remote server".

Is it not enough to make the notification endpoint https? Would graph API not accept localhost?

I there a better way of testing it locally?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` is not an option: there are millions of localhosts on this planet.
There are so-called "debug proxy" services to support this, like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (somewhat promoted by Microsoft) or [localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/) that can convert your localhost into something reachable from outside.

Comment: ngrok would have been fine, but the 2 function endpoints are in the same solution. Each time you run ngrok you would get a different endpoint(unless it is a paid version). Have not used localtunnel before. Is it safe?

Comment: ngrok provides fixed endpoint (called "custom subdomain"), but it's a paid option, that's how they make money. I'm using localtunnel right now (on my own server).